# Guides, tutorials for beginner iOS Game development iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

Am in iOS development. Currently am working for commercial iOS apps for iPhone and iPad. Now, i want to develop game apps for iPhone. But, i just struggling where i need to start with? And what are the skills i need to have for game development? Could you please suggest me any your great ideas on this?

Comment: That's a really broad question. Anyway, you can find help in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check out [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/), it's a nice free open-source framework for game development that has plenty of tutorials (e.g. [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/)) and books written about. I've used it for some time now and I'm very satisfied with it.

Answer (score 5):

This [site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) has many game development tutorials for beginners.